# Usage of a Abstract class and instantiation

Tags: java

This is my question

1. What is the use of a Abstract class even though we cant instantiate a abstract class?
2. is there a indirect way of creating instances of an Abstract class?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, an abstract class is a class that is not fully implemented. If you know that you will have several subclasses of a class, but that you will never declare objects of the class itself, you should consider making the class abstract. Say, for instance, that you have an array of items, and you want them to all act fairly similarly except in certain circumstances. You could make an abstract superclass, and have all these items be members of subclasses of it. Then have the method whose behaviors differ among the different items be abstract in the superclass - but implement them in the subclass. This way, you can put them all in one array (etc) but they will all respond differently to certain method calls.

Answer (score 0):

Did you understand what is an `interface` in java ? It is in fact, a **programming agreement** between the architect, developers. That will **not** contain any method definitions but their signatures. Since architects need to assure to other world creatures who use this code that this works in all of their scenarios. The same way, if some code is so much standard, and an architect cum developer wishes to use it for a de-facto method, he may include that too in an interface. But this distinction made another introduction to java and that is called as `Abstract Class` concept.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes have importance in relation to runtime polymorphism.